# Using jQuery to hide navigation on scroll but reveal on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, css-position

I am planning a two-tier fixed position navigation at the top of my design.

As the user scrolls down the page, I would like the navigation to slide up until the first tier is mostly hidden.

If the user then hovers over the navigation, the container should slide down revealing the first tier again.

This hover effect should not fire if the user is at the very top of the browser window.

Additionally, when the user scrolls back to the very top of the page, the full two-tier navigation should again be fully visible as it is on the initial load.

I'm having trouble chaining these events together using javascript and have had to resort to a combination of `CSS3 transitions` and jQuery `addClass/removeClass` calls.

Additionally, I can only get the whole mish-mash to fire once. So once the user has scrolled down and back up there is no more animation.

My current code is viewable at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zNj7/)

Hopefully this gives an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Can anyone help me bring this monstrosity to life?

Code is as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="nav_wrap">
    <div id="nav_one">
        <h2>Nav One</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="nav_two">
        <h3>Nav Two</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<p>blah blah blah etc...</p>
```

CSS

```css
#nav_wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 120px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_one,
#nav_two {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    background: #111;
}

#nav_two {
    background: #1f4c6b;
    height: 72px;
}

h2, h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

#nav_wrap.fixed {
    margin-top: -42px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0 24px #111;
}

#nav_wrap.down {
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_wrap.drop {
    top: 42px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_wrap.up {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Javascript

```js
var top = $('#nav_wrap').offset()
                        .top - parseFloat($('#nav_wrap')
                        .css('marginTop')
                        .replace(/auto/, 0));

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > top) {
        $('#nav_wrap').addClass('fixed');
        $("#nav_wrap").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass('drop');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).addClass('up');
            }
        );

    } else if (y == 0) {

        $('#nav_wrap').addClass('down');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating your approach. All you actually need to do is toggle one class on scroll in your JavaScript. This CSS will do the rest.

Note: The code will need prefixes added for other browsers (-moz, -o, -ms) and I would look at improving the performance of the `addClass` part of the call in scroll as the event will be getting called a lot.

An example fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/5zNj7/3/).

**CSS**

```
#nav_wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 120px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_one,
#nav_two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    background: #111;
}

#nav_two {
    background: #1f4c6b;
    height: 72px;
}

h2, h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

#nav_wrap{
    -webkit-transition: margin-top .5s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_wrap.scroll {
    margin-top: -42px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 24px #111;
}

#nav_wrap.scroll:hover{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 0) {

        $('#nav_wrap').addClass('scroll');
    } 
    else{

        $('#nav_wrap').removeClass('scroll');
    }
});
```

Comment: Was about to answer this but you beat me to it. This solution is definitely as simple as it gets however I dont think `var top` is needed since that seems to always be 0.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I rushed it to be honest and didn't even think. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this. I think I'd gone too far down one very confusing avenue and couldn't backtrack. Super simple and ace.

Comment: My pleasure! It's easy to do. I've lost count of the amount of times I've had to restart plugins etc because I've overcomplicated things.